# MFC: CCheckListBox items overlap

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2005, winapi

In a dialog template I placed a ListBox, since checked list box is not shown in the visual layout options. I set it to owner-draw and set it up with DDX, changing the associated class variable from type CListBox to CCheckListBox - in other words the only changes I make from what the wizard does for me are set owner-draw, and chnage the member variable type.

in my dialog's `OnInitDialog` method I then test with:

```
m_List.AddString(_T("One"));
m_List.AddString(_T("Two"));
m_List.AddString(_T("Three"));
m_List.AddString(_T("Four"));
m_List.SetCheck(1,1);
```

When I run the list is there, with 4 items and one checked, with the right strings. But, the item heights are wrong. It seems like the height of the checkbox is used to determine the item height, leading to the text overlapping the item below.

Shouldn't the default behavior of the class be to figure this out, without me having to individually set each item's height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN:

> If your checklist box is a default
>   checklist box (a list of strings with
>   the default-sized checkboxes to the
>   left of each), you can use the default
>   CCheckListBox::DrawItem to draw the
>   checklist box. Otherwise, you must
>   override the CListBox::CompareItem
>   function and the
>   CCheckListBox::DrawItem and
>   CCheckListBox::MeasureItem functions.

Looks like you either need to call the default implementation or implement your own MesaureItem/DrawItem. That's probably why the items seem to overlap.

Answer (score 2):

In a check box, string case the following may be sufficient to prevent overlap:

```
class CCheckListBoxEx : public CCheckListBox
{
public:
    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
    {
        // set item height once:    
        if ((GetStyle() & (LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS)) ==
                          (LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS)  && m_cyText == 0)
        {
            SetItemHeight(0, CalcMinimumItemHeight() + 2);
        }

        // add some space between box and string: 
        lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.left += 2;

        CCheckListBox::DrawItem(lpDrawItemStruct);
    }
};
```

Comment: That's the one. A single call to `myCl.SetItemHeight(0,y);` in the dialog's `OnInitDialog` will prevent both overlap (as long as you set a correct height) and the checklist items moving after the first redraw as I have encountered today.